# Where do I find access key in AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm using an Access Key and Secret Key to access S3 from an app. It works. But I can't find the credentials in the console. Where might they be? They're not listed under IAM users.

Comment: Its in your IAM user summary->Security Credentials

Comment: Aha.. found it.

Comment: Cool. If you don't mind then, I will make answer for future reference.

Comment: I ought to delete it and set up a user specifically for S3.

Comment: It depends on why you need this S3 access? If its for instance, then an instance role is better then IAM user.

Comment: Do you mean EC2 instance role?

Comment: Yes, EC2 instance role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IAM Access Key and Secret Key are located (i.e. the option to create them) in IAM user's `Summary` in `Security Credentials` tab.

Edit: based on @jarmod comment.

Comment: The access key is listed there, but the secret key is not, of course.

Comment: @jarmod You have to create it and will have option to download it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS CloudShell to fetch AWS Security Credentials. Open up a CloudShell terminal and run:

```bash
TOKEN=$(curl -XPUT localhost:1338/latest/api/token -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 60")
curl localhost:1338/latest/meta-data/container/security-credentials -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN"
```

Source: [Retrieving AWS security credentials from the AWS console](https://blog.christophetd.fr/retrieving-aws-security-credentials-from-the-aws-console/)